# How do I make a unique variable name in android?

Tags: android, for-loop

I want to display more points on a map. I want to do that with a "for".
My problem is that only the last point is displayed, because variables: point and overlayItem are overwritten each time.
How can I make a unique name for this variables?

```
    List<Statia> arrStatia = datasourceStatia.getAllStatias();      
for (Statia s : arrStatia) {  
    String[] arrCoordonate = s.getCoord().split(",");

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1])),(int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0])));
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1]) + "", Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0]) +"");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);  
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);  
    mapView.postInvalidate();   

    Log.v("xxx", s.getCoord());
}


public class Statia {
    private long id;
    private String statia;
    private long idruta;
    private String coord;
    private String program;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getIdRuta() {
        return idruta;
    }

    public void setIdRuta(long idruta) {
        this.idruta = idruta;
    }

    public String getStatia() {
        return statia;
    }

    public void setStatia(String statia) {
        this.statia = statia;
    }

    public void setCoord(String coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public String getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public String getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return statia;
    }
}

public List<Statia> getAllStatias() {
    List<Statia> statias = new ArrayList<Statia>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.statiiTable,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Statia statia = cursorToStatia(cursor);
        statias.add(statia);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return statias;
}

private Statia cursorToStatia(Cursor cursor) {
    Statia statia = new Statia();
    statia.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    statia.setStatia(cursor.getString(1));
    statia.setIdRuta(cursor.getInt(2));
    statia.setCoord(cursor.getString(3));
    statia.setProgram(cursor.getString(4));

    return statia;
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is not point or overlayItem, it should be the itemizedOverlay.addOverlay() or mapOverlay.addOverlay(). What is itemizedOverlay type?

Comment: itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in an array with size equal to arrStatia.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code I hope it  will work.

```
 for (Statia s : arrStatia) {  
    String[] arrCoordonate = s.getCoord().split(",");

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[0])),(int)(Double.parseDouble(arrCoordonate[1])));
    SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(
            drawable,<<Your Activity name >>.this);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "xxx", "yyy");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);  
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);  
 <<your map view object>>.postInvalidate();    

}
```

Comment: In my code mapOverlays is: mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();. I got an error when I made changes: The method postInvalidate() is undefined for the type List<Overlay>

Comment: oh sorry yar please call that method with you mapview object.

Comment: I made changes but still is displayed only a point on the map

Comment: problem in your "Statia" object please post code where you created "Statia"

Comment: I added class "Statia" bellow

Comment: I need getAllStatias(); implementation

Comment: I added getAllStatias() implementation above

Comment: Yes. 45.7557,21.2541 ; 45.7350,21.2163 ; 45.7507,21.2077 ; 45.7383,21.2411

Comment: everything is fine ,please add a bit long points and use small icon for overlay I think it overriding on previous points please use for loop what i posted.

Comment: I added a bigger distance between points. I used your loop. Every time when I run the program it shows me the last point from database

Comment: please post cursorToStatia(cursor) implementation

Comment: make sure follwing statements should be in for loop

Comment: mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);  
         <<your map view object>>.postInvalidate();

Comment: I update the code above, you can see how look the loop. I added cursorToStatia(cursor) implementation. I added Log.v("xxx", s.getCoord());
and when I run the application I can see the coordinates for all of the 4 points, but only the last one is displayed

Comment: you should craeate itemizedoverlay every time in for loop that is problem

Comment: Can you tell me please how can I add the overlayItem object to an array? I try in this way: List<OverlayItem> arrItem[] = overlayItem; But I got an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from OverlayItem to List<OverlayItem>[]

Comment: I am updating my answer check once

Comment: I don't have this class: HelloItemizedOverlay

Comment: I think you dnt have aware on google maps please see the link @ http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: check my answer agin I replaced HelloItemized overly with your overlay